# Why is Ruby base64 encoded string different from all other base64 encoded strings?

Tags: ruby, base64, aes

For end-to-end encrypted communication between a client and a server, I am implementing an encryption/decryption algorithm.

However, they (encryption/decryption and base64 encoding/decoding) work fine only when it's in Ruby.

But the actual problem I see is with the Base64 encoding of Ruby.

For example, let's say I have this (32 bytes) AES key:

```
"\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6\xC9\xBA\xD6\x9F\xBA\xD2\xC9\xBE\x0F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\x15!/\x13\x8F\xCE\xFB\x15\x9B"
```

that I am using to encrypt data in AES algorithm.

I want to send this key to a client in Base64 encoded format. For that, I am doing (two ways, each produces different encoded output):

**Key in double quotes**

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64("\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6\xC9\xBA\xD6\x9F\xBA\xD2\xC9\xBE\x0F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\x15!/\x13\x8F\xCE\xFB\x15\x9B")
# => "IjGvx8CmybrWn7rSyb4PjiqIhyiby3AVIS8Tj877FZs="
```

**Key in single quotes**

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64('\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6\xC9\xBA\xD6\x9F\xBA\xD2\xC9\xBE\x0F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\x15!/\x13\x8F\xCE\xFB\x15\x9B')
# => "XCIxXHhBRlx4QzdceEMwXHhBNlx4QzlceEJBXHhENlx4OUZceEJBXHhEMlx4QzlceEJFXHgwRlx4OEUqXHg4OFx4ODcoXHg5Qlx4Q0JwXHgxNSEvXHgxM1x4OEZceENFXHhGQlx4MTVceDlC"
```

Output 1 is different from all other libraries: Java, Swift, and [an online site](https://www.base64encode.org/), [another site](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/#.XJyFz0NoScq), which all produce the same output.

Output 2 is the same with other libraries with respect to the output encoding. But I have issues converting AES key and AES encrypted data to be used in single quotes, which is not possible, as I have encrypted data that already have those single quotes and other illegal characters, for which Ruby's Base64 encoding does not work correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean to include the double quote in the beginning also? That might be the reason it’s different. Have you decoded both versions and checked what comes back and that it’s identical?

Comment: "For end to end encrypted communication between client and server, I have been implementing the encryption/decryption algorithm." Don't. Strong, secure, and free encryption software already exists and it's easy to use. Writing your own encryption code is not a good idea and [the result will not be secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged). Instead, [enable SSL](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-https-with-ruby-on-rails) for your application server and use all the time you saved to add useful features to your app.

Comment: ... Observe what happens if you `puts` the strings with the different quotes. The type of quote matters in Ruby.

Comment: And if you're implementing your *own* encryption algorithm, I echo the others in saying for your own benefit, don't. It's not clear if you're using a separate library or if you're actually attempting your own crypto.

Comment: @jordan running yes, I am not writing my own encryption algo, instead I am using Ruby's default OpenSSL library and its AES encryption technics.

Comment: @Sami I literally don't care but because ruby treats it as a string it automatically encloses it double quotes. Though, my concern is, the AES key and the resulted AES encryption data, that seems like a hexa decimal string(as you see the AES key) might have non printable characters. And when to such a string we try to encode it to Base64 in Ruby, its not actually encoding it in the format that could be decoded correctly by other Base64 library of Java, Swift etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you use single quote you will get a different result:

```
a = "\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6\xC9\xBA\xD6\x9F\xBA\xD2\xC9\xBE\x0F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\x15!/\x13\x8F\xCE\xFB\x15\x9B"
#=> "\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6ɺ֟\xBA\xD2ɾ\u000F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\u0015!/\u0013\x8F\xCE\xFB\u0015\x9B"

b = '\"1\xAF\xC7\xC0\xA6\xC9\xBA\xD6\x9F\xBA\xD2\xC9\xBE\x0F\x8E*\x88\x87(\x9B\xCBp\x15!/\x13\x8F\xCE\xFB\x15\x9B'
#=> "\\\"1\\xAF\\xC7\\xC0\\xA6\\xC9\\xBA\\xD6\\x9F\\xBA\\xD2\\xC9\\xBE\\x0F\\x8E*\\x88\\x87(\\x9B\\xCBp\\x15!/\\x13\\x8F\\xCE\\xFB\\x15\\x9B"

a == b
=> false
a.bytes.count
=> 32
b.bytes.count
=> 108
a.length
=> 29
b.length
=> 108
```

So you see single quotes will double escape the escapes.

However, as Jordan Running mentions in comments you should not roll your own encryption, it is not secure please [read this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged) to understand why.

It is a much better idea to use ruby's [openssl](https://github.com/ruby/openssl) gem.  For instructions on how to use it, please refer to [documentation here](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/).

Comment: Looking at the [`String#bytes`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-bytes) output might make the difference clearer in this case. Probably best to make sure they're working with a binary string as well (just in case).

Comment: @muistooshort yeah good idea, I updated, but didn't show the full bytes array but I think this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you need single quote behavior but cannot use single quotes then Ruby has  the `%q` option, that is %q followed by brackets or parens etc surrounding your string, or any char following %q will act as single quote: `%q|it's your string|` or `%q{it's your string}`

Comment: Thanks for answer. This could probably do the trick. But the problem is I already have data in some variable, so now how to use that variable to enclose it within single quote by this method?
%q{#{aes_key}} => #{aes_key} It doesn't evaluates that variable.

Comment: Yes, that is single quote behavior. If you want to evaluate variables you need double quote behaviour - use %Q.